# how can a broadcast receiver get the android system to start a livewallpaper service?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

LiveWallpapers have the permission BIND_WALLPAPER that allows only the system to bind to it. I want the livewallpaper service to be set as the wallpaper, when the device boots up. For this I have written a broadcast receiver that on boot up is meant to start the wallpaper service, using intents. The component of the livewallpaper is set as the component of the intent. At the moment this can detect the wallpaper service but cannot set it due to the permission BIND_WALLPAPER. The manifest of my application includes as follows

```
<receiver android:name=".MyStartupIntentReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>           
    </receiver>
```

The broadcast receiver is as follows :

```
Intent ii = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    ii.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    ii.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.android.livecubes","com.example.android.livecubes.cube1.CubeWallpaper1"));
    context.startService(ii);
```

Ive also tried the above with action.SET_WALLPAPER...category : Launcher/default but everything throws the error permission denied: bind_wallpaper needed. This permission is present at both the service and receiver ends. How can I set the livewallpaper on boot up without chooser/livewallpaper picker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.  You can start the chooser, but you cannot bypass the chooser and actually set the wallpaper in a seamless way.  See comment from Romain Guy here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a22e66002f884718

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can this be done by seeing how the android os does it ? I want to see the android os source code, do you have any suggestions for this ?

Comment: @SDLBING My understanding is that this is truly impossible for the applications programmer to do.  It is not part of the "public" API.  In other words, it requires a "permission" that is impossible for us to get.  You can look at how the chooser functions, but you cannot replicate its methodology.  The best "proof" I have is that I have never seen anyone get this to work.  For instance, the aniPet Aquarium live wallpaper comes with an app to facilitate setting the wallpaper, but all it does is fire up the chooser.

Comment: @SDLBING Source code here: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/wallpapers/LivePicker.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/wallpaper/livepicker